# How to load child components on click of a button angular 4

Tags: angular

Please help needed. I was trying to load child components in parent component on click of a button in parent component.

Suggestion needed please. I gave just a got it working but I am really willing to know is it the appropriate way for doing it. The implementation is as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab" (click)="clickStars()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" (click)="clickFavorite()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" (click) = "clickFollowings()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <app-stars *ngIf="!starsHidden"></app-stars>
      <app-favorites *ngIf="!favoriteHidden"></app-favorites>
      <app-followings *ngIf="!followingsHidden"></app-followings>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    starsHidden:boolean;
    favoriteHidden:boolean;
    followingsHidden:boolean

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.starsHidden = false;
    this.favoriteHidden = true;
    this.followingsHidden = true;
  }

  clickStars(){
    this.starsHidden = false;
    this.favoriteHidden = true;
    this.followingsHidden = true;
  }

  clickFavorite(){
    this.starsHidden = true;
    this.favoriteHidden = false;
    this.followingsHidden = true;
  }

  clickFollowings(){
    this.starsHidden = true;
    this.favoriteHidden = true;
    this.followingsHidden = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: For code reviews, better to ask here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, but all those variables and methods seem like a nightmare. Why not just work with a string, for instance:

```
activeTab: 'STARS' | 'FAVORITES' | 'FOLLOWINGS';

onChangeTab(tab: string){
    this.activeTab = tab;
}
```

And you'd change your template to something similar to this:

```
<button (click)="onChangeTab('STARS')">Stars</button>
```

This would be fine, but it'd be even better if you made your own TabsComponent which would manage all that logic, and you could easily reuse it whereever you wanted.

Comment: Hi Christian ,Thank you for the suggestion. It is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sub-contract Component]
[image: Material component]
**Tab change for loading different components**

---

.html code

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" aria-label="Font Style" (change)="onValChange($event)">
      <mat-button-toggle value="sct">Sub-Contract</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="matr">Material</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <div *ngIf="toggleComponent; else elseBlock">
      <app-sub-contract></app-sub-contract>
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <app-material></app-material>
    </ng-template>
```

**Inside ts file initialize toggleComponent=true**

.ts code

```
 public onValChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.value === 'matr') { this.toggleComponent = false; }
    else { this.toggleComponent = true; }
  }
```